# Scala: implicit conversion to generate method values?

Tags: scala, reflection, pointers

If I have the following class in Scala:

```
class Simple {
  def doit(a: String): Int = 42
}
```

And an instance of that class

```
o = new Simple()
```

Is possible to define an implicit conversion that will morph this instance and a method known at compile into a tuple like this?

```
Tuple2 (o, (_: Simple).doit _)
```

I was hoping I could come up with one for registering function callbacks in the spirit of:

```
doThisLater (o -> 'doit)
```

I functionally have my function callbacks working based on retronym's answer to a [previous SO question](/questions/3238474/how-can-i-obtain-function-objects-from-methods-in-scala), but it'd be great to add this thick layer of syntactic sugar.

Comment: Do you want to be able to do this generically for all classes or only for some specific class?

Comment: And it would have to be not just for `doit`?

Comment: Yes, I would like the technique to work for arbitrary methods on arbitrary classes, but all known at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just eta-expand the method. Sample REPL session,

```
scala> case class Deferred[T, R](f : T => R)
defined class Deferred

scala> def doThisLater[T, R](f : T => R) = Deferred(f)
doThisLater: [T, R](f: T => R)Deferred[T,R]

scala> val deferred = doThisLater(o.doit _)  // eta-convert doit
deferred: Deferred[String,Int] = Deferred(<function1>)

scala> deferred.f("foo")
res0: Int = 42
```

Comment: Thanks Miles! This ended up being more or less exactly what I needed, and as a plus I didn't even need the implicit.